# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't load complete data

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv, sequelize.js, load-data-infile

I am trying to insert 1 million rows of data in a CSV file to MySQL table. Every time I run the following script from node.js, it inserts only portion of rows, which changes every time I run the script.

```
        await mysqlDB.sequelize.query(`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './out.csv' 
                            INTO TABLE product_inventories_product_code_TEMP 
                            COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
                            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                            ESCAPED BY '"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                            IGNORE 1 ROWS;`)
```

I am not sure why is it not inserting all the rows from CSV.

CSV format is simple.

```
id,product_code
26,STM-iY-ofyRH
27,STM-UmHBxU71
28,STM-UmHBeU71
29,STM-UmHBtU71
30,STM-UmHBwU71
```

I am using sequelize raw query to insert. Please help.

Comment: If the script kept failing at a certain fixed row, then I would suspect that this row had bad or malformed data.  That it keeps failing at _different_ rows would imply there is some sort of problem with your connection to the database.

Comment: The same file imported all data when run from shell though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to upload a csv in Mysql using nodejs

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "Your UserName",
password: "Your Password",
database: "Your DB"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
var sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'FilePath' REPLACE INTO TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (Column 
names Comma Separed) set id = NULL;"
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("1 record inserted");
});
});
```